# NSInternalInconsistencyException when loading nib file

Tags: objective-c, iphone, exception

Hello I have the following problem:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/BB022A34-E830-4B04-8A0A-71548502F1B6/MyInternallyIncosistentApp.app> (loaded)'
```

My application is localized in several languages. When the iPhone is set to English it works well, but when I set it to German it gives me the this error. I just push a view controller onto the navigation stack. The nib I'm trying to load is not localized. **Any** help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My view controller xib was in the `en.lproj` folder for the english localization, so it only worked for English. I just had to move it out.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means you have broken some link between you nib file and you view controller, this can happen if you rename a IBOutlet or IBAction but don't update it in your nib.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a really simple view controller with only one IBOutlet which is ok, I just checked it. (it was more complicated before but the functionality from it moved elsewhere).